# Restrict option in Angular JS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Quoting from the Angular JS developer guide:

```
The restrict option is typically set to:
'A' - only matches attribute name
'E' - only matches element name
'C' - only matches class name
```

Is there any matter of efficiency in choosing one over another in any cases? Like: which one will I choose for restricting where I can use both element and class restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

restrict option `'A'` is the default and most common form of directive because they will work across all browsers, including older versions of Internet Explorer, without having to register a new tag in the
head of the document.

**Element or Attribute?**

Use an element when creating something new on the page that will encapsulate a self-contained piece of functionality. For example, if we’re creating a clock (and couldn’t care less about supporting old versions of Internet Explorer) we’d make a clock directive and declare it in the DOM like so:

```
<my-clock></my-clock>
```

Use an attribute when decorating an existing element with data or behavior.

```
<my-clock clock-display="analog"></my-clock>
```

Reference: [ng-book](https://www.ng-book.com/p/Directives-Explained/)